# Have to use pythagoras theorem

Tags: geometry, triangles, quadrilateral

In parallelogram ABCD, the diagonals AC is at right angles to AB.If AB=12 & AC=13. I have to find the area of parallelogram. How can I use Pythagoras theorem here? I do not understand.

Comment: Are you sure you're supposed to use the Pythagorean theorem? It's not what I'd use for this problem.

Comment: Have you drawn the parallelogram?

Comment: yes i have drawn but confused about it.i have to use pythagorean theorem because it is taken  from pythagoras theorem exercise

Comment: I can see no reason to work out the length of BC as you have AB as the base and AC as the hieght

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. Take a look at: http://www.algebra.com/algebra/homework/Pythagorean-theorem/Pythagorean-theorem.faq.question.459618.html

Answer (score 3):

The area of a parallogram is the product of base and height. In your case, the base is AB and the height is AC, so the area is just $12\cdot13=156$, so no need of Pythagoras' theorem. You can use it, however, to calculate $BC=\sqrt{AB^2+AC^2}$.

Comment: thanks a lot..i will try to solve it using pythagoras theorem.

Answer (score 0):

As sranthrop says, there is no need to use Pythagoras thm.

Try solving this one :

In parallelogram ABCD, the diagonals AC is at right angles to DB.If AB=12 & AC=13. Find the area of parallelogram, using  Pythagoras theorem. (Rhombus).

Typo in your exercise?